# Getting around Boost Multi-Index container's constant elements

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have some data class which is expensive to copy, but must be mutable, as it is frequently updated according to events. I also need a multi-index container to hold many such classes. I'm trying to set it up using boost::multi_index. For example:

```
struct MutableAndExpensiveToCopy {
    int some_value;
    std::map<int, std::string> some_huge_map;
    std::map<int, std::string> an_even_bigger_map;
}

struct CanBeMultiIndexed
{
    // "Payload" - its fields will never be used as indices
    MutableAndExpensiveToCopy data;

    // Indexes        
    int         id;
    std::string label;
}

typedef multi_index_container<
    CanBeMultiIndexed,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<member<CanBeMultiIndexed, int, &CanBeMultiIndexed::id>>,
        ordered_non_unique<member<CanBeMultiIndexed,std::string,&CanBeMultiIndexed::label>>
    > 
> MyDataContainer;
```

My problem is that multi_index treats elements in the container as constants (in order to keep the integrity of all of the indices). For example, the following won't compile:

```
void main() {
    // put some data in the container
    MyDataContainer container;
    CanBeMultiIndexed e1(1, "one"); // conto'r not shown in class definition for brevity
    CanBeMultiIndexed e2(2, "two");

    container.insert(e1);
    container.insert(e2);

    // try to modify data
    MyDataContainer::nth_index<1>::type::iterator iter = container.get<1>().find(1);
    iter->data.some_value = 5;  // constness violation
}
```

I cannot use the `replace()` method, as it is expensive to copy the payload class.
I'm aware of the `modify()` method, but using it seems cumbersome, since in my real program, the "payload" class may contain numerous fields, and writing a functor for each and every one it out of the question.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** After some playing around, I've tried replacing the data element with a shared_ptr to `MutableAndExpensiveToCopy`:

```
struct CanBeMultiIndexed
{
    // "Payload" - its fields will never be used as indices
    boost::shared_ptr<MutableAndExpensiveToCopy> data;

    // Indexes        
    int         id;
    std::string label;
}
```

This worked, and I was able to compile my `main()` including the data-modifying code:

```
void main() {
    ...
    iter->data->some_value = 5;  // this works
    ...
}
```

This pretty much gives me what I wanted, but I'm not sure why this works, so:

1. Does this code does what I intended, or is there some caveat I'm missing?
2. How come this works? Does the constness of the shared_ptr does not apply to its `->` operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `ImMutableAndExpensiveToCopy` seems precisely to be the opposite --mutable, since you're trying to change its contents in the example. Try simply this:

```
struct CanBeMultiIndexed
{
    mutable ImMutableAndExpensiveToCopy data;
    int         id;
    std::string label;
}
```

(and possibly change the name `ImMutableAndExpensiveToCopy` for consistency.)

Comment: @Joaquin - by `ImMutableAndExpensiveToCopy` I meant to say "I am mutable and expensive to copy". I'll fix the example to make this clear.

Comment: OK, I got it now :-) Anyway, does `mutable`- qualifying solve your problem?

Comment: @Joaquin - nope. As stated in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html), the iterator returned from, e.g. `find()` is, by definition, const. This is in order to guarantee index integrity. BTW, AFAIK, class/struct members are mutable by default, so the `mutable` qualifier is redundant.

Comment: @bavaza: I'm pretty sure Joaquin knows the iterators are constant, seeing as he's the author of the Boost.MultiIndex library. Did you try his suggestion, or just decide it won't work? You seem to think that `mutable` is the opposite of `const`, which isn't the case. Members are not mutable by default.

Comment: @Juaquin, Interjay: I've tried the `mutable`, and the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is solved, but is `mutable` not a very ungood way of c++ programming!

Comment: @bavaza "*class/struct members are mutable by default*" - this is incorrect. class/struct members are *non-const* by default, but not mutable.