# Best way to modify non-indexed field of Boost Multi-Index item: modify vs mutable

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-multi-index

I have a situation similar to the one described in this thread: [Getting around Boost Multi-Index container's constant elemets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528517/getting-around-boost-multi-index-containers-constant-elemets). In short, I have a [boost multi index container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) holding a struct like this:

```
struct Data {
    Controller controller;
    const int indexed_data;
}
```

My indexed data never changes, but the controller does. So, my first approach was to do all I need in a [modify](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#modify) call:

```
container.modify(it, [](auto& data) {
    data.controller.nonConstFunction();
});
```

Apparently this works for me, but I was performing some tests to understand the behaviour of this method when an exception is thrown inside the lambda (which will happen in my case), and I was surprised with the result:

```
struct employee {
    int id;
    std::string name;
}

typedef multi_index_container<
    employee,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(employee,int,id)>>
    >
> employee_set;

employee_set es;    
es.insert(employee{0,"Joe"});
es.insert(employee{1,"Carl"});
es.insert(employee{2,"Robert"});
es.insert(employee{4,"John"});

try {
    auto it = es.find(4); // John
    es.modify(it, [](auto& employee) {
        employee.id = 1; // Same ID of Carl, should be erased
        throw std::runtime_error("test");
    });
} catch (const std::runtime_error& err) {
    // handle error...
}
```

After this, if you print the contents of the container you get:

```
0 Joe
1 Carl
2 Robert
1 John
```

Although without throwing the exception and only changing the employee's ID to one already existent, the hit on the index is detected and the employee being modified is erased.

Like I said, I don't perform any changes to my container's keys, but after finding out about this I am concerned. Is this a bug on the library? Are there any other situations that can lead to an invalid state of the indexes? I also couldn't find a way to "reprocess" the indexes to a valid state besides manually deleting/modifying one of the "invalid" entries.

Apart from that (and going back to my own case), is using [modify](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#modify) the best approach to actually call methods on my controller, or should I follow the advise of the [thread beforementioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528517/getting-around-boost-multi-index-containers-constant-elemets) and declare my controller `mutable`? The latter looks quite dangerous for me because one could easily mess around with the index by declaring anything `mutable`, but as I just showed, the safe way of doing it has just proved to be not so safe after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's remarkable that you bring this issue up, because the behavior of `modify` has remained stable for 12+ years until Jon Kalb [pointed my attention to a closely related problem in 2016](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12542).

In short, `modify` expects the user-provided modifier not to throw unless it doesn't change the keys of the elements, in which case undefined behavior ensues, as you have discovered. Documentation says so (italics mine):

> **Exception safety:** Basic. If an exception is thrown by some user-provided operation *(except possibly `mod`)*, then the element pointed to by `position` is erased.

Whether this is a bug or a design flaw is debatable, but in any case I recently changed the implementation so that [your use case will now result in the element being erased](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/multi_index/doc/release_notes.html#boost_1_66). This updated behavior will be available in the upcoming Boost 1.66 release (Dec 2017), when the docs will read:

> **Exception safety:** Basic. If an exception is thrown by some user-provided operation *(including `mod`)*, then the element pointed to by `position` is erased.

In the meantime, you need to protect your modifier from after-modification throws --sorry about that. If you're in desperate need of the new `modify` behavior you can download Boost.MultiIndex source code and patch your local Boost installation.

Comment: Thank you! I confess I had some trouble understanding the excerpt you highlighted, although it indeed looked very much to me it was related to my problem. Anyway, assuming I won't modify any keys when executing `mod`, would you rather keep using `modify` or just declare the controller `mutable` as you suggested yourself on the other thread I mentioned?

Comment: Well, there is a trade off here between safety and performance: `modify` is an expensive operation involving checking consistency (i.e. making sure no keys have been modified) while making things `mutable` has zero overhead. I'd go for `modify` until your profiling indicates more performance is needed.